# Does removing the dashboard widgets cancel the SQL queries in WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, dashboard

I'm looking to gradually remove as many queries that WordPress does that I don't find necessary for speed.

I read this article on [smashing magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/09/secrets-high-traffic-wordpress-blogs/) and one thing mentioned under "COMMENTS" was:

> For instance, I killed the ‘Right Now’ and ‘Recent Comments’ sections
>   of the Dashboard.”

I know there's a way to remove meta boxes from the dashboard like so:

```
function remove_dashboard_widgets(){
remove_meta_box('dashboard_right_now', 'dashboard', 'normal'); // Right Now
remove_meta_box('dashboard_recent_comments', 'dashboard', 'normal'); // Recent Comments
remove_meta_box('dashboard_incoming_links', 'dashboard', 'normal'); // Incoming Links
remove_meta_box('dashboard_plugins', 'dashboard', 'normal'); // Plugins
remove_meta_box('dashboard_quick_press', 'dashboard', 'side'); // Quick Press
remove_meta_box('dashboard_recent_drafts', 'dashboard', 'side'); // Recent Drafts
remove_meta_box('dashboard_primary', 'dashboard', 'side'); // WordPress blog
remove_meta_box('dashboard_secondary', 'dashboard', 'side'); // Other WordPress News
// use 'dashboard-network' as the second parameter to remove widgets from a network dashboard.
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets');
```

My question is: by doing this, will this stop the query to the database completely? Or does it still do it THEN not show it, still taking up a query? I really don't want to change the core files if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the callback functions that do the actual work never gets called when you do this, so yes, it does stop the database queries.

cachegrind with widgets
[image]

cachegrind without widgets
[image]

dashboard widget methods are located in [wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php)